# How to analyse categorical data (0/1) with structural zeros?

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, categorical-data

I have a categorical dependent variable (emerged/not emerged) and two predictors 1) treatment (continuous time, 28 to 35h) and 2) group (test/control). I want to know if test group emerges earlier than control group. I have a n=20 in each group+treatment, but I get structural zeros as control group never emerges before 32h (see data below).  Thus I apparently cant use a simple logistic regression directly to compare my two groups.

Here is the data, values are %emergence (calculated) :

Treatment(h)___28___29___30___31___32___33___34___35
Control________0____0____0____0___59___70___100__100
Test__________50___70___90__100__100__100___100__100

Anybody can suggest a method to make this work? Note that I'm prety green in stats, I would appreciate a few details with the suggestions! :)

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem you face? I do not see why the zeroes are an issue in a logistic regression framework.

Comment: Well, I read that one of the conditions for the logistic regression to produce correct estimates is that it shouldn't have cells with 0 events.  I may be wrong though...?

Comment: I don't really understand that objection. The logistic regression will estimate the probability of emergence as a function of time here. That probability will be close to zero till the 31-32 hour time period. Try it out.

Comment: After some reading, I was left with the impression that the odds ratio would be inflated for the test group, if I had 0 cells in the control. So you suggest this is not the case?  The IV I'm really interested in is the group, and using a logistic reg, it comes out very significant, so I am trying to describe my observations using the coeffs and odds ratio.

Comment: You don't need to calculate an odds ratio at all, since you have a continuous variable here. You can simply calculate the probability of emergence as a function of time in control and in test groups.

Comment: Ok, that sounds right. Excuse my trivial question here, but should I then use another statistical test on my probabilities, to test if they are significantly different?  I'm using the glm function in R for my logistic regression.

Comment: If your only question is did group A emerge before group B, then it shouldn't be too difficult to construct a randomisation test for this.

Answer (score 1):

With a binary target and categorical features, logistic regression can be viewed as a type of log-linear model or contingency table analysis. In chapter 10 of Wickens book, *Multiway Contingency Tables Analysis for the Social Sciences*, approaches to adjusting degrees of freedom and model results for the presence of structural zeros are discussed. Wickens main point is that "data tables with structural voids lack a complete factorial structure," a necessary requirement for logistic regression tests of independence, where "impossible cells assert themselves as dependencies," pps. 246-247.

One option is to step back from considering time as continuous. Discretizing time would place the model design into the form of a contingency table. This permits one to ignore the missing cells and test for quasi-independence of the valid cells only.

Wickens suggested solution is to employ an iterative proportional fitting algorithm to construct the maximum likelihood estimates which he goes through on a step-by-step basis -- much too involved for a response on this blog. In essence, in constructing the test statistic, the structural zero cells are ignored and degrees of freedom are adjusted or reduced for the missing cells, devising a new test statistic based only on valid cells.

Apologies if this is too involved for a stats newbie but, in point of fact, your problem is not a big one and is quite readily answered. The only issue is that these methods go well beyond the full factorial chi-square tests of independence dealt with in stats 101 courses. There are many, many references and resources on log-linear models, contingency table analysis, and categorical data analysis. While Agresti's books are among the standard, stats "go-to" resources, I prefer Wickens for the greater clarity and lucidity of his writing. To be able to fully address, understand and answer your question, you need to drill into those references.

Comment: Stats 101 is pretty much my level indeed. :)  But I had already understood that my data could be treated as a contingency table, and I had thought of making categories for the time treatment, which could give me a 2x2 table without 0 cells for example.  Thanks for your answer.